# How to save data to the Model in an non-Appliactioncontroller running in the background periodically

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Post` Mode ,and a controller called `happy_robot_controller`,which will periodically crawl certain web sites , gather the data I am interested in , and then save to the `Post` Model.

skeleton of `happy_robot_controller.rb`:

```
craw the web site and get the interested data, save to title and content variables 
#save to the Model
Post.new(:title=>title, :content=>content).save
```

Executing `ruby happy_robot_controller.rb` :

```
root@pierr-desktop:/work/web/yy/app/controllers# ruby happy_robot_controller.rb 
happy_robot_controller.rb:54: uninitialized constant Post (NameError)
```

How should I be able to access the `Post` class? Should `happy_robot_controller` inherits `ApplicationController` like `PostController` do?

OR, should I put `happy_robot` in the `models/post.rb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this "crawler" code should go into a rake task.

Start by creating the file `RAILS_ROOT/lib/tasks/happy_robot.rake` and put in the following:

```
namespace :happy_robot do
  task :crawl => :environment do
    # crawling code goes here
    Post.new(:title=>title, :content=>content).save
  end
end
```

You can then run this code by executing `rake happy_robot:crawl` from the command line (within your project directory of course).

Here is a nice `rake` tutorial: http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial